# jquery how to find child element

Tags: jquery

```
<div id = "buttons" class="card-content" class= "ui-g-3">
    <button id = {{item.dist}} pButton type="button" (click) = itemClicked(item) label= {{item.dist}}></button>
</div>

$("#"+feature.properties.COUNCIL).addClass("ui-button-success");
```

It works and my button class changes, 
now and time when my clicked event fires I want to remove previously added class from button and assign to new selected element.

I am trying like this but not working.

```
$("#buttons").find('.ui-button-success').removeClass("ui-button-success");
```

Comment: On what element do you add the class?

Comment: its dynam. between 1 to 14 change each time when

Comment: its same as button id

Comment: do you want to remove class of clicked button ?

Comment: @DhawalPatel  your marked answer will not work in the case what you asked to me in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(".ui-button-success").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-button-success");
});
```

Comment: its work but I have one more problem its removeclass from my first div (id="one") buttons also <div id="one">...buttons...</div> <div id="two" >..buttons..</div>. I want to removeClass("ui-button-success") only inside my second div that id is "two".

Answer (score 0):

Try this : bind click event handler to all buttons inside div. Add class to clicked button and remove from rest of the buttons like below

```
<div id = "buttons" class="card-content" class= "ui-g-3">
          <button id = {{item.dist}} pButton type="button" (click) = itemClicked(item) label= {{item.dist}}></button>
 </div>

$(function(){
  $("#buttons").on("click","button",function(){
     $("#buttons .ui-button-success").removeClass("ui-button-success"); 
     $(this).addClass("ui-button-success");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to google this kind of things.

### This will help you.

```
$('div#buttons').find( "button" ).removeAttr('class');
```

or

```
$('div#buttons').find( "button" ).removeClass('yourclass');
```

or

```
$('div#buttons').children().removeAttr('class');
```

or

```
$('div#buttons').children().removeClass('yourclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-

```
$( "#buttons" ).children().removeClass("ui-button-success");
```

To find child elements you can visit this link https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: it will not work in the case asked by OP to me:- `its work but I have one more problem its removeclass from my first div (id="one") buttons also <div id="one">...buttons...</div> <div id="two" >..buttons..</div>. I want to removeClass("ui-button-success") only inside my second div that id is "two".`

Comment: Like you are making button-id dynamic {{item.dist}} on-click function you can get current "id" attribute value and check which is having "ui-button-success" class then you can remove the same class for that "id". Hope it helps...